# How to transform the mesh by points?

Tags: scripting

[image]

How to achieve this with script?

Thanks！

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix


def make_matrix(origins, x, p):
    a = x-origins
    b = p-origins

    z = a.cross(b)
    if z.magnitude>0:
        z = z.normalized()
    else:
        return None

    y = z.cross(a).normalized()
    x = a.normalized()
    
    M = Matrix()
    w = origins.copy()
    w.resize_4d()
    M[0], M[1], M[2] ,M[3] = x.resized(4), y.resized(4), z.resized(4), w
    M.transpose()

    return M   


    
    
t0 = Vector((2,3,0))
t1 = Vector((5,1,0))
t2 = Vector((8,3,0))

f0 = Vector((1, -1, 0))
f1 = Vector((5, -1, 0))
f2 = Vector((3, 1, 0))    

obj = bpy.data.objects["from"]

m_from = make_matrix(f0, f1, f2)
m_to = make_matrix(t0, t1, t2)

M = m_to @ m_from.inverted()

scale_factor = (t1 - t0).length / (f1 - f0).length
M = M.Diagonal((scale_factor, ) * 3 ).to_4x4() @ M
offset = t0 - M @ f0
M = M.Translation(offset) @ M

if obj.mode == "EDIT":
    matrix_world = obj.matrix_world
    matrix_world_i = matrix_world.inverted()
    me = obj.data 
    m = M @ matrix_world
    
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    for v in bm.verts:
        p = m @ v.co
        v.co = matrix_world_i @ p
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

[demo.blend](https://github.com/ZeronoFreya/Gallery/blob/master/demo.blend)

Comment: What is the logic here? Do you want to transfer positions by topology (indices)?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Question has been modified. This is what I am currently doing, thank you

Comment: Hello, @MarkusvonBroady et al. ,instinctively, I think mapping the triangle formed by the points of the original shape to the target triangle, with `mathutils.geometry.barycentric_transform` might hit the spot? But I'm very slow at scripting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get get the 3 outermost vertices and get consistent ordering (to avoid matching clockwise with counter-clockwise) by sorting them by angle:

[Sorting vertices counter-clockwise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/263191/60486)

The question is a deep well of possible optimizations, e.g. you can use `heapq` for quicker sorting (getting just 3 highest elements) when looking for the 3 vertices away from the mean point. But how do you find a mean point? You can use `numpy` to sum up all coordinates and divide by the number of them, you can also use numpy to efficiently calculate coordinate lengths, which is easier if you first calculate a transformation matrix to offset all verts so that they the mean is at the origin (`data.transform` will do that efficiently). Also at least for some geometries (I'm not sure any would work, but the one you present will), you can create a transformation matrix, consisting of the mentioned translation, then rotation, then scaling, then translating back.

However with the example provided it would be an overkill so let's keep it simple and use Robin Betts' (our Python black horse) most excellent approach:

```py
from bpy import data as D
from math import atan2
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.geometry import barycentric_transform

ob_from = D.objects['from']
ob_to = D.objects['to']

coords_from = [ob_from.matrix_world @ v.co for v in ob_from.data.vertices]
coords_to   = [  ob_to.matrix_world @ v.co for v in   ob_to.data.vertices]

mean_from = sum(coords_from, start=Vector()) / len(coords_from)
mean_to   = sum(coords_to,   start=Vector()) / len(coords_to)

peaks_from = sorted(coords_from, key=lambda c:(c-mean_from).length)[-3:]
peaks_to = coords_to

ordered_peaks_from = sorted(peaks_from, key=lambda c:atan2(*(c-mean_from).yx))
ordered_peaks_to   = sorted(peaks_to,   key=lambda c:atan2(*(c-mean_to).yx))

mat_inverted = ob_from.matrix_world.inverted()

for v in ob_from.data.vertices:
    wco = ob_from.matrix_world @ v.co
    wco = barycentric_transform(wco, *ordered_peaks_from, *ordered_peaks_to)
    v.co = mat_inverted @ wco
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, he met my needs perfectly. I can specify the coordinates and order of the three points, but your script taught me a lot